# How to set a Global Variable in SSRS Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc, reportbuilder3.0

Condition:

When value of one field in a row is greater than 1,000,000 then it's font size must be set to 6pt, otherwise, default 9pt

I used this expression formula for that:

> =IIF(Fields!UNIT_RATE.Value > 1000000, "6pt", "9pt")

for the uniformity of the report, other fields in all row must follow its font size based on the font size of this field.. but the challenge is, the formula is testing this condition per row..

so it results to something like this

[image]

Is there ways or right approach to fix this? where in the second row must also follow to that of first row, which auto adjust based on the condition provided?

**My initial solution**

I am thinking of creating a GLOBAL VARIABLE TO CHECK first if there is a unit rate in the dataset which value is more than 1,000,000 then this global varible mist be TRUE.otherwise False, this will then be used as a varibale in each fields font size formula expression..

BUT I DONT KNOW how to implement this as I am new to REPORT BUILDER

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if the max value of the field in the dataset exceeds 1000000

```
= Iif( max(Fields!val.Value, "YourDatasetName")>=1000000, "6pt", "9pt" )
```

For multiple fields you can use multiple OR conditions

```
 = Iif( max(Fields!val1.Value, "YourDatasetName")>=1000000 OR max(Fields!val2.Value, "YourDatasetName")>=1000000 OR ...., "6pt", "9pt" )
```

In order to use it in a global variable, go to report properties and enter your expression like in the image below and set the variable value in the font size property of each textbox

[image]

Comment: where to put this formula? will this filter all the rows in the dataset?

Comment: but the rows are dynamic in number. the number varies per result per data